# Retrive data from Firebase in ArrayList for graph

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, graph, firebase-realtime-database

I must retrive data from firebase, and use it into a graph. I'm using a library for graph.

I use a addValueEventListener for retrieving data, and it work.
With my code the app crash with this error:

> One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object.

The item in firebase are 2, than the array list labels is not populate with data from firebase. I don't know my error.

How can I fix my code and connect data in arraylist?

```
DatabaseReference mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user-specialita").child(getUid()).child(mPostKey).child("content");
    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Specialita object and use the values to update the UI
            Specialita_2 specialita = dataSnapshot.getValue(Specialita_2.class);
            // [START_EXCLUDE]

            LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

            ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
            entries.add(new Entry(4f, 0));
            entries.add(new Entry(8f, 1));
            //entries.add(new Entry(6f, 2));
            //entries.add(new Entry(2f, 3));
            // entries.add(new Entry(18f, 4));
            // entries.add(new Entry(9f, 5));

            LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
            ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
            labels.add(specialita.title);


            LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset);
            dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS); //
            dataset.setDrawCubic(true);
            dataset.setDrawFilled(true);

            lineChart.setData(data);
            lineChart.animateY(5000);

            Toast.makeText(Alpha.this,"success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: LineData data = new LineData(labels, dataset); In this line first argument should be ILineDataset then how it is working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could tell us which Framework or Library you are using to create your charts.

Guessing from the error message I assume the issue is not Firebase related but lies within your use of the Chart API. In your example you have 2 elements within your entries list but add only one label to your labels List. The API on the other hand seems to expect one label per entry, but that's just an assumption.